# Firebase/Android Studio: How do I check for a substring in firebase data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two nodes in my firebase. One called JOBS and one called USERS. I want to retrieve all jobs that have the same **job_type** as the users **job_interests**. For example, in this case, the user Willow is interested in Pet Care and Tuition jobs. I want the jobs that have **type** Pet Care or Tuition to be extracted. Job 1 in this case.

This is my **Job node:**

[image]

This is my **User node:**

[image]

Based on my research, this is possible using *startAt* and *endAt* functions. I tried the below code. However, nothing gets displayed on the screen. I am new to android and firebase so I'm not sure if what I'm doing is right. Help is appreciated, thanks.

```
package com.example.oddsynew;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecommendedFragment extends Fragment {
    DatabaseReference usersRef, jobsRef;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    RecyclerView nearYouList;
    ArrayList<Job> list;
    HomeAdapter adapter;
    Query query;
    FirebaseUser u;
    String userID, jobinterests, jobtype;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recommended, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        u = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userID = u.getUid();
        usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userID);
        jobsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Jobs");

        nearYouList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.nearYou);
        nearYouList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        list = new ArrayList<Job>();

        adapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(), list);
        nearYouList.setAdapter(adapter);

        try {
            jobsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        jobtype = ds.child("job_type").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.e("TAG", " " + jobtype);

                        query = usersRef.orderByChild("job_interests").startAt(jobtype).endAt(jobtype + "/uf8ff");
                        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        Job j = ds.getValue(Job.class);
                                        list.add(j);
                                        System.out.println(list);
                                    }
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                    Log.e("TAG", "LOL" + query);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: You can't have substrings in firebase. startAt() and endAt() is used to set the start and end index of the result set of the query.

Comment: In the case of firestore, you will store the user interests as an array and make an "in" query in the jobs collection. Maybe someone can tell how to do this in realtime database.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a 'jobsOfType' db node containing all job types. Under each job type I would list the jobs that are of that type. It is then easy to retrieve all jobs of a specific type.

An alternative to this would be to use job type as the first part of the Job key eg. 'Pet CareJob1', you can then use startAt endAt on the key to get all jobs per job type. However using spaces in the key is not recommended. If you go this route then I would use specific codes to identify job types, rather then 'free text' strings. This applies as a general comment, so you should probably implement codes for job type identifiers.

On the 'User' node I would store the job types, that the user is interested in, as a list/array. Then when you read the user record, you iterate through the array and for each entry you read the 'jobsOfType' node to retrieve the list of jobs of that type.